# How seamless scroll down to next page is achieved without reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How seamless scroll down to next page is achieved without reloading the page and showing both like this [News Paper page](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/world/south-asia/Nepal-facing-medical-crisis-as-supplies-run-short/articleshow/49854313.cms) and also the page url is also changing while scrolling down ?

Comment: @DinoMyte I dont have a clue how to implement this ?.So I dont have a representation of this .I am dumbstruck meaning how its loaded is it loaded using ajax on scroll and appended down the or how the scroll takes place and simultaneous address bar change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 parts are there.

Part 1: Load the new contents when scroll is at the bottom of the page and append the new content to the bottom of the page eg: [jQuery.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Part 2: Change the url - works in most modern browsers

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/your-new-page-url");
```

More info on pushState [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState)

Comment: Thanks I was also thinking along the same lines :D .I was just reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page